# Random 'Access Is Denied' while Windows IOT remoting on the Pi3

Tags: powershell, .net-core, raspberry-pi3, remoting, windows-10-iot-core

I have a .NET Core 2.0 console program (not ASP) that I have on my Pi3. Using the Windows IOT Dashboard from my main computer (Win10), I open up PowerShell as admin and run my program's exe. I want this program to run 24/7.

It does great for hours, sometimes even a day, but I keep getting these seemingly random "Access is Denied" messages which terminate the program. Often terminating the remote session as well if I have it open.

An example of a couple are below:

1.

```
Processing data from remote server <IP> failed with the following error 
message: Access is denied. For more information, see the 
about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

2.

```
Processing data for a remote command failed with the following error message: 
Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting 
Help topic. + CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingDataStructureException
```

I tried to find the `about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic` but couldn't find relevant results.

Basically, I have no idea how to even debug this to figure out what is wrong. It it evading all my crash logging and error handling which makes me think it doesn't have to do with my code. To the same idea, I can leave it for days on my main computer without issue.

How can I find what it is trying to access and why it is denied? How can I give it the appropriate permissions?

Note about the program: Aside from a few JSON files , the program does not interact with any external files to my knowledge (excluding DLLs, etc). The program reads from the JSON files at the start and runs successfully. Occasionally, the program may update one of these JSON files, which it also does successfully. My program was not trying to write to any JSON file when these errors occur. Every time the error occurred my program has been in an idle state.

Comment: Could it be that the session times out? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-5.1#pssessionoption

Comment: I don't think so? If that were the case wouldn't the error always happen after X time? There are also cases where I open the remote session, start the program, and then close the remote session and it does fine for hours.

Comment: @anon Can you run your program's exe via CommandLine in DefaultApp of Windows IoT Core to see if it can reproduce this issue?

Comment: Running the exe from the web interface and so far 3 days has had no issues. Guess it is something with Powershell.